# Unable to use setup in test class @testSetup

Tags: apex, test-setup

When i use the @testSetup method, and try passing the myContact in

`ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myContact);`

the line returns error `Argument cannot be null`

```
@isTest
    public class ContactButtonOnAccountExtensionTest {

        public static Account myaccount;
        public static Contact myContact;

        @testSetup 
        public static void setup(){
           myaccount = new Account(
                Name = 'My Account'
            );     
             insert myaccount; 
            myContact = new Contact(
                Firstname = 'New Contact',
                Lastname = 'Contact Lastname'
            );
        }

        @isTest
        public static void positivetestoncontact(){    

            Test.startTest();    

            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myContact);
            System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('account', Id.valueOf(myaccount.Id));
            ContactPageExtensionNew testcontact = new ContactPageExtensionNew(sc);
            PageReference pageRef = Page.NewContactPage;        
            Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);        

            String nexturl = testcontact.save().getUrl(); //call all your function here
            Test.StopTest();

            System.assert(myaccount.Id != null, 'The contact is being saved!');
            System.assertEquals(myContact.FirstName, 'New Contact');
            System.assertEquals('/'+ myaccount.Id, nexturl);

        }   

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll always have to query the data created in [Test Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm) method in all your test methods. You cannot store them with any member of the class.

```
@testSetup public static void setup(){
   Account myaccount = new Account(
        Name = 'My Account'
    );     
    insert myaccount; 
    Contact myContact = new Contact(
        Firstname = 'New Contact',
        Lastname = 'Contact Lastname'
    );
}

@isTest public static void positivetestoncontact(){    

    // query the contact    
    Contact myContact = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

    Test.startTest();
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(myContact);
    // other code

}
```

Comment: This behavior is what prompted me to post [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC). Of course, it got shot down, but still...

Comment: Ah too bad, I am not a fan of @testSetup due to this. The comment from Salesforce also make sense.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm going to present my idea to people who can make things happen as soon as I get a chance. I have a laundry list of items I want to see fixed.

Answer (score -1):

While using @testSetup you cannot have member variables since the values won't be assigned to them. So you basically will have to query for the records you have inserted or create a method just to set up data without the @testSetup notation.
**Also where are you inserting contact?**

```
     public static void setup(){
           myaccount = new Account(
                Name = 'My Account'
            );     
             insert myaccount; 
            myContact = new Contact(
                Firstname = 'New Contact',
                Lastname = 'Contact Lastname'
            );
       }
```

so at the start of every test method you could fo something like this :

```
static void testMethod demo() {
 setup();
}
```

Comment: I am writing this test class for vf standard controller extension, so the contact is inserted in the save() method of the controller class which is instantiated in line  String nexturl = testcontact.save().getUrl();